# Configuring default settings for new Git repositories

Tags: git

Currently, when I create a new git repo on my computer, fast-forwarding is enabled by default for merges. I would like to turn this off for all future repos to be created on my computer - is there a way to do this? I know that you can run

```
git config --add merge.ff false
```

within a single repo, but I want this setting to be the default for all future repos.

Comment: `git config --global merge.ff false`

Comment: Cool, thanks!  How would I make it automatically include the `--rebase` flag when doing a `git pull`?

Comment: @Ryan `pull.rebase true`. See [gitconfig](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for more config options.